# Get Data From Google Analytics API

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api

I need to get the following data  from **GoogleAnalytics** API

1. New, Returning, Visits, Organic, Paid, Social, Referral, Direct etc
2. Bounce Rate, Pages per Visit, Time per Visit.

I have never worked on GoogleAnalytics before. Please forgive me its a basic or broad question.

**EDIT :** I have found a class `GAnalyticsAPI` which I am using and its working

```
 string authToken    = GAnalyticsAPI.GetAuthorizationToken("my_email_id", "my_password");
            string metrics = Server.UrlDecode("ga:visits");
            string dimensions   = Server.UrlDecode("ga:country");
            string filters = Server.UrlDecode("-ga:visits");

            XmlDocument xmld = GAnalyticsAPI.GetDataFeed(.........);
           return xmld;
```

*but can anyone explain(provide detail documents )about the query structure `metrics ,dimensions,filters  etc` so i can make query for the data I need. thanks*

Comment: Have you tried google site for info? https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/  Also,  Ive created a little library for that, but its at home at the moment, if nobody comes back to till later I can try to throw an example and explain how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation. It will tell you what are valid dimension and metric combinations. 
[Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Also, the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) is tremendously helpful in experimenting with dimensions and metrics to find the combination you need.